# Scoring solution for Farkle (dice game)?

Tags: python, dice

I've written the following function on Python (3.3) to take a list of 6 integers and return the maximum score for [a game of Farkle](http://officialfarklerules.com/rules-of-the-game/). While the results are correct I don't feel it's a very Pythonic implementation. I'd like to hear from the community on how I could make it better and more Pythonic. Any and all tips are most welcome!

```
"""
    written and tested in Python 3.3.6
"""

from random import randint

def score(my_roll, sides=6):
    """
        Calculate a Farkle score using the traditional scoring method, which is:
            4 1s:     2,000 points
            3 1s:     1,000 points
            Single 1: 100 points
            Single 5: 50 points
            Triple of any non-1 number:    100 x number showing
            Quadruple of any non-1 number: Double the triple score

        Notes:
            - Doubles score nothing (unless a 1 or a 5) as above
            - All scoring dice must be rolled in a single turn (i.e. they
            are not additive over turns)
            - Rolling all 6 will be two sets and scored accordingly
                [4] + [2]
                [3] + [3]
                [2] + [2] + [2]

        Examples:
            1,1,1,5,5,5 ==> 1500 (1000 for 1s + 250 for 3 5s)
            1,1,1,1,6,6 ==> 2000 (2000 for 4 1s)
            5,3,6,5,3,3 ==> 400 (300 for 3 3s + 100 for 2 5s)
            1,2,2,3,3,5 ==> 150 (100 for a 1 and 50 for a 5)
    """
    #create a table to hold the count of each die roll
    dice_array = [0] * sides
    score = 0

    #add up the number appearances of each die roll and store it in the table
    for dice in my_roll:
        dice_array[dice-1] += 1

    """
        based on the above scoring, determine the MAXIMUM score; in actual Farkle the
        player would choose which die to 'bank' and which to re-roll
    """
    for (i, count) in enumerate(dice_array):
        dice = i + 1  #this makes it easier to keep track of the die we're on

        if dice == 1:
            if count == 6: score += 2200
            if count == 5: score += 2100            
            if count == 4: score += 2000
            if count == 3: score += 1000
            if count in [1, 2]: score += (count * 100)
        else:
            if count >= 4: score += (dice * 200)
            if count >= 3: score += (dice * 100)
            if (dice == 5 and count != 3): score += (count * 50)                             

    return score

#test cases
while True:
    roll = input("Enter 6 values (1-6) separated by a space: ")
    roll = [random.randint(1,6) for i in range(0, 6)] if roll == "" else [int(i) for i in roll.split(' ')]
    print(str(score(roll)) + " : " + str(roll))
```

Comment: My only comment is that your examples seem to contradict themselves. `1,1,1,5,5,5` should be `1500`, for example (1000 for triple 1s and 500 for triple 5s). You specifically call out quadruple 1s as being 2000, but ALL quadruples are double their triple score.

Comment: Cheers for the sharp eye on the example! The rules I was going with, that I linked to, say that it's only 1,000 for 4 1s (no other numbers): A roll of a 1 is worth 100 points.
A roll of a 5 is worth 50 points.
Three (3) dice rolled at the same time with the same value is worth 100 times the face value, for example: three 2’s rolled is 200 points and  three 5’s rolled is 500 points.
** One exception to this rule is that three 1’s rolled is 1,000 points rather than 100 points.

Comment: I was writing my code for this hoping it would come out simple and ended with this mess: http://pastebin.com/fk3J79Sf , well this is life...

Comment: @Caridorc oh gosh that's awful....

Comment: Your comment *"Doubles score nothing (unless a 1 or a 5) as above"* is a bit unclear, it looks like you meant *"Single or Double 1: 100 points each, Single or Double 5: 50 points each"*

Comment: and I totally can't understand *"Rolling all 6 will be two sets and scored accordingly: [4] + [2], [3] + [3], [2] + [2] + [2]"*

Comment: And in the case of a quadruple, both your quadruple and triple clauses will score it, which is not what you wanted: `if count >= 4: score += (dice * 200)`, `if count >= 3: score += (dice * 100)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### "Pythonic" programming

Code is "pythonic" when it expresses its intention clearly, is easy to read or even looks like pseudo-code, and uses as little low-level garbage as possible. Let's take a look at a couple examples of low-level work in your code:

```
dice_array = [0] * sides
score = 0
for dice in my_roll:
    dice_array[dice-1] += 1
# as an aside, this isn't an array, it's a list.
```

This is wonky because it buids a fixed-size list, then plays with values-as-list-indexes to get a count. That might be fast, but it's certainly ugly. Let's not do that.

```
import collections

counts = collections.Counter(my_roll)
```

This is much better. It builds a dict-like object, a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that has the counts for any dice present in the roll. `counts[non_rolled_die]` will throw a `KeyError` while `counts.get(non_rolled_die, 0)` will act like your current code does.

Your counting loop isn't a whole lot better. Let's look:

```
for i, count in enumerate(dice_array):
    dice = i + 1
```

We'll stop here for just long enough to mention that `enumerate` takes a keyword argument `start` that lets you tell it where to start counting from. This should be:

```
for die, count in enumerate(dice_array, start=1):
```

But since I switched to using a `collections.Counter`, we can just do:

```
for die, count in counts.items():
    if die == 1:
        if count == 6: score += 2200
        if count == 5: score += 2100
        if count == 4: score += 2000
        if count == 3: score += 1000
        if count in [1, 2]: score += (count * 100)
    else:
        if count >= 4: score += (dice * 200)
        if count >= 3: score += (dice * 100)
        if (die == 5 and count != 3): score += (count * 50)
```

First of all, avoid these repeated `if` statements. Try instead:

```
    if die == 1:
        if count == 3: score += 1000
        elif count == 4: score += 2000
        elif count > 4:
            score += 2000 + (count - 4) * 100
```

However there's a better approach. We already know that the triple value for each number is `100 * number`, except for `1` which is `100 * 10 * number`. Let's use that!

```
for die, count in counts.items():
    die_score = 0
    if count == 4:
        die_score += die * 2000 if die == 1 else die * 200
        count -= 4
    elif count == 3:
        die_score += die * 1000 if die == 1 else die * 100
        count -= 3
```

This should handle triplets and quadruplets of any value, and removes from `count` the number of dice consumed by the grouping. Now let's look at single dice values.

```
    if die in [1, 5]:
        single_value = 100 if die==1 else 50
        die_score += single_value * count
```

In fact we can factor some of that out to drop the if block.

```
    # somewhere earlier in the function
    single_values = {1: 100, 5:50}

    # then inside the loop we're looking at here....
    die_score += single_values.get(die, 0) * count
```

Finally at the end of our loop (just before exiting it), we add the single `die_score` to the roll-wide `score`.

```
    score += die_score
```

#### Testing

I'm a big fan of the [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module for writing tests. In your case `doctest` may work better (since you've written examples already that only have to be tweaked slightly to use `doctest`), but if you start writing more intense functions, it's important to be able to grow your testing suite appropriately. Let's write some tests!

```
# ./test_farkle.py

import unittest
import farkle

class FarkleTests(unittest.TestCase):
    cases = [([1,1,1,5,5,5], 1500),
             ([1,1,1,1,6,6], 2000),
             ([5,3,6,5,3,3], 400),
             ([1,2,2,3,3,5], 150)]

    def testRolls(self):
        for got, want in self.cases:
            self.assertEqual(farkle.score(got), want)
            # fails test if `farkle.score(got) != want`
```

#### A change in data structure

It should occur to you that for every `(die, count)` pair, `score` increases by a given amount. This means we can hardcode that data in something like a `dict`.

```
# {die: {count: value, ... }, ... }
valuedict = {1: {1: 100,
                 2: 200,
                 3: 1000,
                 4: 2000,
                 5: 2100,
                 6: 2200},
             2: {3: 200,
                 4: 400},
             3: {3: 300,
                 4: 600},
             4: {3: 400,
                 4: 800},
             5: {1: 50,
                 2: 100,
                 3: 500,
                 4: 1000,
                 5: 1050,
                 6: 1100},
             6: {3: 600,
                 4: 1200}}
```

Now your function becomes pretty simple!

```
def score(my_roll, sides=6):
    valuedict = ...  # the whole deal above
    counts = collections.Counter(my_roll)
    score = 0
    for die, count in counts.items():
        score += valuedict[die][count]
    return score
```

Or even more simply:

```
def score(my_roll, sides=6):
    valuedict = ...
    counts = collections.Counter(my_roll)
    return sum(valuedict[die][count] for die,count in counts.items())
```

Comment: You are incredible! Thank you. Wish I could give you point++! This is exactly the type of breakdown I was looking for. I've just finished two intro python courses and this was my first self test. I knew there was a ton that needed work to make it look like python and you nailed it.

I'd actually started the whole thing with collections so I could use the .count method but I kept getting an error that collections couldn't be found. Hence this route!

Comment: `collections` is a stdlib module, just be sure to import it at top level.

Comment: N.B. the "classic" Farkle rules (as I remember them) are [here](https://cdn.shptrn.com/media/mfg/1725/media_document/8976/FarkleRules_E.pdf?1401226825). When you start getting into more complicated combinations (e.g. four of one die, two of another), the hardcoded solution will be useless.

Answer (score 1):

**Make the examples runnable**

If You have made the effort of writing your examples, it is a waste to let them sit there doing nothing. Here is the format required to run them.

```
>>> score([1,1,1,5,5,5])
1250
...
```

Look into the `doctest` module.

Comment: I did have that but I thought I'd put them in the comments for people who didn't get my language. I thought providing the self-entry mechanism was more fun, too.